# how to call multiple columns in a stored procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm new to stored procedure and I don't know much.
I'm testing with an example. Could you help me?
Here is my stored procedure

> DELIMITER $$
>
> DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS dictionarytable$$
>
> CREATE PROCEDURE `dictionarytable`(id VARCHAR(20),name
>   VARCHAR(20),work VARCHAR(20),place VARCHAR(20),mobileno
>   VARCHAR(20),bike VARCHAR(20),car VARCHAR(20),homeno
>   VARCHAR(20),dictionaytype VARCHAR(20),meaning VARCHAR(20),sentence
>   VARCHAR(20),antonym VARCHAR(20),synonym VARCHAR(20))
>
> BEGIN
>
> select
>   id,name,work,place,mobileno,bike,car,homeno,dictionaytype,meaning,sentence,antonym,synonym
>   from dictionary INTO dictionarytable; END $$

DELIMITER ;
I wanted id,name,13 columns from dictionary(table) to be called in stored procedure dictionarytable
the query in the Begin is wrong could you specify a query to display all 13 columns

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass field values INTO the procedure, you can pass them INTO user variables,  declared variables or OUT paramaters. Note, that only one record can be passed when INTO clause is used. For example:

```
SET @var1 = NULL;
SELECT column1 INTO @var1 FROM table;
```

If you want to copy more then one record, then you can use [INSERT INTO...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html) statement to copy data-set to second table. For example:

```
INSERT INTO table2 SELECT column1 FROM table;
```

Also, if you want to use variables or parameters as identifiers (field names in your case), then you should use [prepared statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html).

Comment: thanks devart insert select statement created wonders for me.but how do we call multiple columns in hibernate mapping hbm file.here i'm pasting sample code for hibernate   
 @NamedNativeQuery(
 name = "callStockStoreProcedure",
 query = "CALL dictionarytable(':id',':name',;:work)",
 resultClass = Dictionary.class
 )
}) 
hbm class code <sql-query name="callStockStoreProcedure">
 <return alias="dictionary" class="entity.Dictionary"/>
 <![CDATA[CALL dictionarytable(:id)]]>
 </sql-query>

Comment: I have nothing to say about the hibernate. I think you should ask about the mapping in another question, with 'hibernate' tag.